# Can I simplify this delegate call when branching to other methods?

Tags: c#, delegates

```
public MyDelegate HandleRemoteChange => (data) => DataSwitch.Invoke(data);

private Func<ChangeMetadata, Action<ChangeMetadata>> DataSwitch => (d) => d.ChangeType switch
{
    ChangeType.Foo => onFoo(d),
    ChangeType.Bar => onBar(d),
};

private Action<ChangeMetadata> onFoo(ChangeMetadata metadata) => (o) =>
{
    // do something
};

private Action<ChangeMetadata> onBar(ChangeMetadata metadata) => (o) =>
{
    // do something else
};
```

I've got this branching logic to handle `MyDelegate` invocation by using a `enum ChangeType` property of the class `ChangeMetadata`

I think it's needlessly verbose. Can you refactor this code to fix onFoo and onBar, because I don't understand why I need these `Action<T>` defined with both an argument and an anonymous method taking o as a parameter. Any other cleanup would be appreciated. For example, `MyDelegate` expects a void type which doesn't smoothly play well with the pattern matching (where I have to use an `Action<T>` instead), maybe there's some easier way to pattern match the void MyDelegate to a simple void method.

**EDIT:**

Ok, so the following is cleaner, and not a compiler error, but can it be cleaner? This syntax I gleaned from the MSDN docs is kinda strange,

```
internal MyDelegate HandleRemoteChange (ChangeMetadata data) => data switch
{
    OverrideSetChange os => delegate{ onSourceOverrideSet(os); },  
    // OverrideSetChange os => (os) => onSourceOverrideSet(os) <- doesn't work 
};

private void onSourceOverrideSet(OverrideSetChange data){}
```

Lambdas don't work here because the pattern match performs the silent cast to the covariant metadata type, but that then breaks the signature. For some reason an anonymous closure works but the lambda doesn't. (At least that's my understanding)

Comment: Just to be clear, `MyDelegate` is declared as `delegate void MyDelegate(ChangeMetadata data)` and `ChangeType` is an enum?

Comment: @Sweeper that is correct.

Comment: Unrelated: I'd suggest to make such switches exhausting. I.e. add a default branch that throws.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can just use a `Dictionary<ChangeType, MyDelegate>` to store the mappings between `ChangeType` values and the methods to call.

Then you can select the correct delegate just by accessing the dictionary.

```
private Dictionary<ChangeType, MyDelegate> dict;

// note that this could return null! There are other ChangeType values than Foo and Bar!
public MyDelegate HandleRemoteChange => (data) => dict.GetValueOrDefault(data.ChangeType);
// also perhaps turn HandleRemoteChange into a method instead?

private void onFoo(ChangeMetadata metadata) {}

private void onBar(ChangeMetadata metadata) {}

// initialise dict in the constructor...
dict = new() {
    { ChangeType.Foo, onFoo },
    { ChangeType.Bar, onBar },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to jump through hoops just to pattern match, you can use a good ole `switch`

```cs
public MyDelegate HandleRemoteChange => data =>
{
    switch (data.ChangeType)
    {
        case ChangeType.Bar:
            onBar(data);
            break;
        case ChangeType.Foo:
            onFoo(data);
            break;
    }
};

private void onFoo(ChangeMetadata metadata)
{

}


private void onBar(ChangeMetadata metadata)
{
    // do something else
}
```